# Не обрабатывается клик по маркеру в Yandex Mapkit при попытке перехода к другому фрагменту

Tags: android, yandexmapkit

Пытаюсь добавить обработчик клика по объекту на карте **addTapListener** для перехода к другому фрагменту, но столкнулся с проблемой: при добавлении собственно строки навигации **findNavController().navigate...** нажатие вообще никак не обрабатывается (без неё хотя бы сообщение в лог выводится).

```
val marker = binding.mapView.map.mapObjects.addPlacemark(Point(lat, lon))
    marker.opacity = 0.5f
    marker.setIcon(ImageProvider.fromResource(requireContext(), R.drawable.marker_icon))
    marker.addTapListener { _, p1 ->
        Log.d(TAG, "navigateToFragmentTwo: ")
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fragmentOne_to_fragmentTwo)
        true
    }
```

Comment: Думаю, тут маловато исходных данных будет. Неизвестно, что за панель, как добавлена, находится ли она вообще через findNavController(). Тут больше шансов получить ответ будет от поддержки Яндекс, если отошлёте им минимальный пример.

Comment: Второй фрагмент пока самый простой с статическим текстом в центре, аргументы никакие пока не передаю - пытаюсь хотя бы переход осуществить. При добавлении строки для навигации findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fragmentOne_to_fragmentTwo) в простую кнопку - нажатие на кнопку нормально отрабатывается и осуществляется переход на fragmentTwo.